# How to test what material is applied to an object in Unity

Tags: if-statement, unity-game-engine

I have a diamond-sprite and I want to be able to change the colour of the diamond from white, it's original colour to green. However, I can not figure out how to do this.

```
    public class MoveControl : MonoBehaviour {
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) )
    {
        if (GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color == Color.white)
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
        }  
    }

  }

}
```

This above code is what I have right now and it only works if the material applied to the sprite, being white, is a sprites/default shader. This may not sound like a big problem but whenever I apply a different material of a different colour, such as blue, and change its settings so it has a sprites/default shader, the sprite becomes invisible.

I'm new at Unity and if someone could help me out, it would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but this may help you.

```
public class Material : MonoBehaviour {

Renderer renderer;
Color currentColor;
Color originalColor;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    renderer = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>(); //If you don't know the gameObject is the object this script is attached to
    originalColor = renderer.material.color; //The original color ( in your case white )

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {


    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {

        if (renderer.material.color == originalColor) { //Here we are checking if the color on the object is the original color
            renderer.material.color = Color.blue;   
            currentColor = renderer.material.color; //Here we are assining the current color
        }

    }

}
```

}

I created a material and assigned it to the gameObject in the editor.

Comment: In the console, it says that "The referenced script on this Behaviour is missing!". It is not working as expected.

Comment: @NathanielOriecuia try this http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/347443/the-referenced-script-on-this-behaviour-is-missing-2.html